# Como disparar o evento cancel quando clico fora do modal ou aperto esc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap, modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

Problema com saída do modal `$uibModal`:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                     animation: true,
                     templateUrl: 'detalhes_leitura.html',
                     controller: 'ModalController',
                     size: size,
                     backdrop:true,
                     keyboard:true,
                     resolve: {
                         dados: function () {
                             return $scope.result_items;
                         }
                     }});
```

Quando clico fora do modal, ele fecha o modal, mas não dispara o evento de cancelar. Sei que se mudar backdrop:'static' e keyboard:false, ele trava o fechamento do modal, mas desta maneira não fica legal, quero apenas que ele execute o método cancel dentro do controle do modal quando a pessoa clicar fora do modal.

```
$scope.cancel();
```

Como fazê-lo disparar?

Comment: Ajuste este JSFiddle à sua modal e veja se funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/ndfmcun5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No AngularUI, a propriedade `result` do objeto retornado por `$uibModal.open` é uma `Promise` que resolve quando o modal é fechado usando a função `$uibModalInstance.close` e rejeita quando o modal é fechado através de `$uibModalInstance.dismiss` (chamado também quando o usuário clica fora do modal).

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: 'detalhes_leitura.html',
  controller: 'ModalController',
  size: size,
  backdrop: true,
  keyboard: true,
  resolve: {
    dados: function() {
      return $scope.result_items
    }
  }
})

modalInstance.result
  .then(function(valor){
      // modal fechado usando $uibModalInstance.close
  })
  .catch(function(valor){
      // modal fechado usando $uibModalInstance.dismiss
      // ou clicando fora do modal
  })
```

No controller do seu modal teria algum código parecido com isso:

```
app.controller('ModalController', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, dados){
   $scope.fecharModalSucesso = function(){
      $uibModalInstance.close()
   }

   $scope.fecharModalCancelar = function(){
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss()
   }
})
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal).

Comment: mas onde ele iria chamar  o método fecharModalCancelar? sei que o método fecharModalSucesso dá para colocar no botão da template do modal. mas o desistir não existe... eu tive que fazer uma nova div pegando a tela toda para ele fazer o clique.

Comment: Você pode chamar a função `fecharModalCancelar()` em um botão de cancelar, por exemplo.